# Linux kernel boot configuration

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am working on SH architecture, I found

```
CONFIG_ZERO_PAGE_OFFSET=0x800000 
CONFIG_ENTRY_OFFSET=0x00001000
```

in my kernel configuration.
Can any one tell me, what is significance of these offsets? How are they used by kernel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`CONFIG_ZERO_PAGE_OFFSET` - the default offset of zero page ( The zero page is a single page of physical memory filled with zeroes, maintained by the operating system. - from [here](http://landley.net/writing/memory-faq.txt) )
`CONFIG_ENTRY_OFFSET` - offset of start entry in kernel
You can see usage of those variables in kernel [makefile](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/sh/boot/Makefile?v=2.6.33#L61)